# How to make this SQL query, with only one SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I´m having trouble creating a particular SQL query, in one query only (I can't go two times to the database, for design architecture, trust me on this) here are the statements:

I have four tables:
**Questions, 
Locations, 
Countries, 
Regions**

This are some of their fields:

```
Questions
    id
    description
Locations
    id
    type (could be 'country' or 'region')
    question_id
    country_or_region_id (an id, that holds either the country or the region id)
Countries
    id
    name
Regions
    id
    name
```

What I want to get is this:

**Example:**

```
1       What is your name?        Venezuela, Colombia              South America
```

**Format:**

```
question id,      question description,       countries,        regions
```

---

*Edit:* For those who ask, I'm using MySQL

*Edit:* For those who say it is a bad design: I didn't create it, and I can't change the design, I just have to do it, as it is now.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problem are you running into?  Could you provide sample data/desired output?

Comment: How do you expect the system to know whether `country_or_region_id` in the `Locations` table is a country or a region id?

Comment: @hanleyhansen That is what the type field is for. But you have no link from Country to Region.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you on?

Comment: @theB3RV That's what i mean. Does he want to `JOIN` on both? Either or? Is he expecting the system to just know (not gonna happen)? Does he need a query where he `JOIN`s on either one? Will this logic take place in code? Is there any guarantee that there won't be a country and a region with the same id?

Comment: So you need this for `mysql`AND `sql-server`???

Comment: @hanleyhansen it is unlikely that there will be that restriction, in my opinion this is a poor table design for the current application. In my opinion the Locations table need not exist. Just add question_id to Countrys and Regions

Comment: @DrCopyPaste No, I delete the sql-server tag.

Comment: @theB3RV thanks, but I didn't design the database, and can't change it...

Comment: @GoatCO The format desired is on the description, can you check it ?, I'm about to update with the code that I have tried.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales Format is one thing, but sample data and sample output are far more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is MySQL:

```
SELECT  q.ID,
        q.Description,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.name) AS countries,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.name) AS regions
FROM    Questions q
        INNER JOIN Locations l
            ON l.question_id = q.id
        LEFT JOIN Countries c
            ON c.id = country_or_region_id
            AND l.type = 'country'
        LEFT JOIN Regions R
            ON R.id = country_or_region_id
            AND l.type = 'region'
GROUP BY q.ID, q.Description;
```

If this is SQL- Server:

```
SELECT  q.ID,
        q.Description,
        countries = STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + c.name
                            FROM    Locations l
                                    INNER JOIN Countries c
                                        ON c.id = country_or_region_id
                                        AND l.type = 'country'
                            WHERE   l.question_id = q.id
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''),
        regions = STUFF((   SELECT ', ' + r.name
                            FROM    Locations l
                                    INNER JOIN Regions r
                                        ON r.id = country_or_region_id
                                        AND l.type = 'region'
                            WHERE   l.question_id = q.id
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM    Questions q;
```

Comment: It is for MySQl, I am gonna check your code, and let you know.

Comment: Well, this is what I needed, the **GROUP_CONCAT** function ! Although, my solution is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Locations table and add question_id to the Regions and Countries table

```
select Q.id, Q.description, C.name as country, R.name as region 
from Questions as Q join Countries as C join Regions as R 
where Q.id = L.question_id and Q.id = C.question_id and Q.id = R.question_id;
```

Comment: I can't remove a table, it is an already working system, can't touch it :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT questions.id
     , questions.description
     , Group_Concat(countries.name) As countries
     , Group_Concat(regions.name) As regions
FROM   questions
 INNER
  JOIN locations
    ON locations.question_id = questions.id
 LEFT
  JOIN countries
    ON countries.id = locations.country_or_region_id
   AND locations.type = 'country'
 LEFT
  JOIN regions
    ON regions.id = locations.country_or_region_id
   AND locations.type = 'region'
GROUP
    BY questions.id
     , questions.description
```

Comment: why you didn't you 'GROUP BY' ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales I lazily used `DISTINCT` instead.

Comment: would using DISTINCT cost more ?, I think it is less efficient.

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales you're correct group by is more cost effective as Distinct iterates through results again and omits duplicates